# How to create a Tensor with specific values?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor with shape NxM.

I'd like to create another tensor with the same shape, filled with ones up until a certain column (might be different for each row) and the rest of it filled with another value (let's say 10 for the example).

How I do that?

Comment: it depends of how you define index of split column in a row.

Comment: the first row I want to put 10 from index i1 till the end, the second row from index i2 till the end, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this can help you:

```
input = tf.Variable([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]], dtype = tf.float32)
indices = tf.constant([1, 4, 2])
X = tf.ones_like(input)
Y = tf.constant(10, dtype = tf.float32, shape = input.shape)
result = tf.where(tf.sequence_mask(indices, tf.shape(input)[1]), X, Y)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(input))
    print(sess.run(indices))
    print(sess.run(result))
```